# Does not contain a definition for 'Owner' when calling new window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, structure, hashtable

I'm rewriting my project from VB.net to C#

I simply would like to call "AxisAssignWindow" from "MainWindow" here

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh0cc.png)

```
AxisAssignWindow ownedWindow = new AxisAssignWindow();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.ShowDialog();
```

somehow it says

'AxisAssignWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Owner' and no extension method 'Owner' accepting a first argument of type 'AxisAssignWindow'

Same message appears for following "ShowDialog", and "this.close" in AxisAssignWindow.xaml.cs

EDIT: The First Problem seemed to be caused by Mahapps, I might post their forum. I removed the second problem as it seemed another problem after I have found it.

Comment: As I edited OP, The First Problem seemed to be caused by Mahapps, I removed the second problem as it seemed another problem after I have found it and might question again after trying some possible solutions.

Comment: I solved it. I had to follow Mahapps guide more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, just leave out the Owner part.  There is no concept of form ownership except in an multiple document interface (MDI) setting.  As you are doing ShowDialog(), the new form will be modal, active until dismissed.

```
testform form = new testform();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it also says 'AxisAssignWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' and no extension method 'ShowDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'AxisAssignWindow' could be found